# not removing duplicates using lodash difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Using lodash, is it possible to remove one array from another while avoiding removing duplicates?

I'm currently using _.difference

```
// this returns [4]  
_.difference([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3])

// I want it to return [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Your problem is very ambiguous. It's unclear which occurrence of each element should be removed form the 1st array. Suppose you have these arrays: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]`. What do you expect in the result?

Comment: hmm, good point. I'd like to remove the first instance of each item in the second array. so that would be [1,2,1,2,3,4]

Comment: AFAIK lodash has no such method ready for use. I would suggest to use nested for loop.

Comment: done, see my answer below. I'm sure it can be improved on. It will do for now. thanks! If you want to answer I'll tick yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i would do it by pure JS

```js
var arr1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3],
  result = arr2.reduce((p,c) => {var idx = p.indexOf(c);
                                 return idx === -1 ? p : (p.splice(idx,1),p)}, arr1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment from @hindmost, I used a loop.

```
var tempArray = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,2]

_.each([1, 2, 3], function(value) {
  tempArray.splice(tempArray.indexOf(value), 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It will return 4 Because `_.difference` Returns the new array of filtered values.I tried java script solution. Hope it will help you.

```
function keepDuplicate(array1, array2){
  var occur;
  var indexes = [];
  _.each(array2, function(value){
    _.each(array1, function(ar1value, index){
     if(value === ar1value){
      occur = index;
     }
    });
    indexes.push(occur);
  });
  _.each(indexes, function(remove, index){
    if(index === 0 ){
     array1.splice(remove, 1);
  }
  else{
   remove = remove-index;
   array1.splice(remove,1);  
  }
 });
 return array1;
}
```

`keepDuplicate([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3])`

It will Return `[1, 1, 2, 2, 4]`

Comment: this code will remove single value from first array which is in second array.